# CSS not placing text in middle of DIV asp.net c#

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I've got the following page. http://jsfiddle.net/r1mymj25/. I'm having trouble trying to get the text in the QDetails to be placed in the middle of the DIV using CSS.

```
#QDetails{
   height:25px; 
   top:40px; 
   background-color:white; 
   text-align:center; 
   font-size:small; 
   border-color:black; 
   border-width:2px; 
   border-style:solid; 
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
   vertical-align:middle;
}
```

I've managed to centre it but not place it in the middle. I've tried "vertical-align:middle;" but no joy. What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: What does this have to do with asp.net?

Comment: possible duplicate of [vertical alignment of elements in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div)

Comment: Use line-height as equal to height. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

Create a `span` inside the `div` and then set `text` to the span like below

```
<div id="QDetails">
    <span id="msg"></span>
</div>
```

This is the css class

```
#QDetails
{
   height:25px; 
   top:40px; 
   background-color:white;
   font-size:small; 
   border-color:black; 
   border-width:2px; 
   border-style:solid; 
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
   display: table;
   text-align:center;
}

#msg
{
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Try this. It will make it exact.

Comment: No joy i'm afraid Ganesh. Still produces the same.

Comment: I'm sorry about not working on you, but check this fiddle same code its working perfectly... [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ganeshgaxy/fyojL13t/)

Comment: I've seen you fiddle now tell me exactly which element you want to center align it.

Comment: its the div: <div id="QDetails"> all the text in that ie: Lee Barker. It seems ok when it's just text but the text goes to the bottom when there are images as well within the div which are needed.

Comment: okay hold on. so you need to align the images with text too??

Comment: [jsfiddle to middle everything inside div](http://jsfiddle.net/ganeshgaxy/34qe3abs/) look at this, everything is in middle... hope this will help

Comment: Nearly there thank you Ganesh. It's now in the middle but it's shrunk the Div QDetails down. <http://jsfiddle.net/r1mymj25/3/>

Comment: you have to properly arrange the following divs, that will fix it. don't worry.

Comment: If you find these this post useful accept as the answer. That will help us bro.

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align : middle` only works within tables (as far as I know).

If you include the following in your style definition it should work: `line-height:25px;`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `top:40px`(not doing anything) and apply `line-height` property like below.

```
#QDetails{
height:25px; 
background-color:white; 
text-align:center; 
font-size:small; 
border:2px solid black;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
line-height:25px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/r1mymj25/1/)

Comment: Hi Suresh. Yes that works but as soon as you put the images back in the same happens.